# How to start `mtr` in the d mode? (or: how to send a keypress to a console app)

Tags: networking, keyboard, ping, console

I love `mtr` for [measuring my internet connections](https://superuser.com/questions/206470/a-better-way-to-monitor-my-internet-connection-other-than-ping). Unfortunately the mode that I use it in can only be reached by pressing <kbd>d</kbd> as far as I know.

This is the standard mode, with ping times:
[image: standard mode]

This is the mode I like, which shows the last 64 pings in this case:
[image: last n pings]

I've been using `mtr` for years now but the `man` page doesn't mention any `--option` to switch to the "d-mode", nor are there configuration files. I tried using `yes` but I haven't been able to get what I want with `yes`. Is there a way to send a <kbd>d</kbd> to `mtr` after it has been started?

Comment: I've experimented with this myself, was never able to find a solution. I tried various `echo d | mtr` type approaches, nothing ever worked... :-(

Comment: In my testing, I found that if you start `mtr`, and leave it running, then later press <kdb>d</kbd> you'll get the history. Not perfect, but at least it's possible to pull it up, and press <kdb>d</kbd> when there's an issue...